# How to set up a test in OBIEE as a hyperlink?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, obiee

There is such an SQL request:

```
Select 
(((('<a href="https://help.company.ru/sd/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$'::text || scall.id) || '">'::text) || (scall.title)::text) || '</a>'::text) AS call_link
```

Produces this result:

[image]

In the next step, I connect to OBIEE 12c, do the analysis and set up the text as a hyperlink, but it does not work out correctly:

[image]

Tell me how to do it right?

Comment: Did you try using the HTML format under Column Properties > Data Format?

Comment: I have expanded the comment into an answer so that the question can be marked as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by selecting the HTML format under Column Properties > Data Format:

[image: screenshot]